# How to include HTML in OGNL expression language in Struts 2

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, ognl

I am working on struts 2. I was doing a `projection` of a collection in my JSP page using OGNL expression language.

I have 1 list based collection in my `action` class, that I am accessing on JSP page like this:

```
<s:iterator value="lsEmp.{name + '<b>---</b>' + address}"> //lsEmp is a list based collection
<s:property /><br>
</s:iterator>
```

I want the output like this:

rajiv **---** N.Delhi

nakul **---** Mumbai

vinay **---** Banglore

//"---" being **bold**.

But my `<b></b>` tag in `<s:iterator value="">` is not getting accepted. And it is printing as it is like this:

```
rajiv <b>---</b> N.Delhi

nakul <b>---</b> Mumbai

vinay <b>---</b> Banglore
```

I want to know is there any way to enable HTML in OGNL expression.

Comment: You don't need the projection for this.

Comment: @AleksandrM then, what to use. In which cases should I use projection then. Can you advice me further.

Comment: You can just iterate your `lsEmp` and in `<s:property />` tag use `name` with `address` and set `escapeHtml` attribute to false.

Comment: @AleksandrM I am facing one more difficulty now. `escapeHtml` is not available for `<s:select>`. Was trying this : `<s:select list="lsEmp.{name+'<i> lives in <i>'+address}" escapeHtml="false"/>`. How to do this. can you advice me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn off escape html symbols when printing to out

```
<s:property escapeHtml="false"/><br>
```

Comment: I am facing one more difficulty now. `escapeHtml` is not available for `<s:select>`. Was trying this : `<s:select list="lsEmp.{name+'<i> lives in <i>'+address}" escapeHtml="false"/>`. How to do this. can you advice me.

Comment: A `template` (other than default) can be used for rendering the element.