# How to display HTML markup content from database record to browser properly in Struts 2?

Tags: html, struts2, escaping, html-escape

I have a simple text stored in the database record: `Hello` wrapped in an `h1` tag.

When I print this record in the JSP with the `<s:property />` tag, it displays:

```
<h1>Hello</h1>
```

While I want it to be displayed like:

> ## Hello

How can I get the interpreted value, instead of the source value ?

Comment: Can you please be more specific and add some code you already have tried. Else nobody will understand your problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to include HTML in OGNL expression language in Struts 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26684025/how-to-include-html-in-ognl-expression-language-in-struts-2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `escapeHtml` attribute of the `<s:property/>` tag to `false` because, for security reasons, it is `true` by default:

```
<s:property value="myVar" escapeHtml="false" />
```

Read more [on the docs](https://struts.apache.org/docs/property.html).